# How do you declare a function in Scala that returns itself (or another function with the same signature)?

Tags: scala

First the background - I am writing some code to decode messages received from a socket.  The nature of sockets means that these messages, received as `ByteString`s may be complete, truncated or concatenated with other messages.  The messages themselves are broken into a common header which contains the length of the variable data which follows.

My plan was to have functions that read the parts of the message, for example the first read could read the length of the variable data, the second the variable data itself.

When one of these methods is called, I want it to return the next operation which could be the next logical operation in the read sequence or itself if the particular read could not be performed because all the data required is yet to be received.

In the case that the data received from the socket is perfectly framed, the read operations would alternate between `readLength` and `readData`.  However when data is read in multiple chunks from the socket it may be that the read operations follow a `readLength`, `readData` and `readData` pattern.

Hope that made sense.

What I want to do is something like this (which won't compile because of the cyclic reference):

```
type ReadFunction = (ByteBuffer) => ReadFunction
```

So that I can declare something like this:

```
def readLength(buffer: ByteBuffer): ReadFunction = {

  if (buffer.limit - buffer.position > 4) {

    return readData(buffer.getInt)
  }
  else {

    return readLength
  }
}

def readData(length: Int)(buffer: ByteBuffer): ReadFunction = {

  if (buffer.limit - buffer.position > length) {

    val data: Array[Byte](size)
    buffer.get(data) 

    //process data

    readLength   
  }
  else {

    readData(length)
  }
}
```

Now I know I can (and actually have) solve this by defining the read operations as classes that extend a common trait and return instances of each but that seems rather un-Scala like.

So my question is - how do you define a function that can return itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use cyclic reference in `type` declaration, but you can use it in `class` or `trait` declaration like this:

```
implicit class ReadFunction(f: Int => ReadFunction) extends (Int => ReadFunction) {
  def apply(i: Int) = f(i)
}

lazy val read: ReadFunction = { i: Int => println(i); read }

scala> read(1)(2)(3)
1
2
3
res0: ReadFunction = <function1>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I ended up with - as I'm new to Scala was wondering if the same could be done purely with functions :-)